# How do you tell which commit, tag, and branch a git submodule should be on without checking it out

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a project in git.  It has a couple of submodules.  Without going into the submodule and doing a git status or similar, is there a way to tell which commit, branch, and tag it the main project thinks it should be on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `git submodule modulename` gives you the commit without going into the submodule directory, followed by the result of [`git describe`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-describe), which gives you most recent tag:

```
$ git submodule ext/fiji
808e757481874dfd493b8cc08a484235ce807ec2 ext/fiji (Fiji-Madison-23-g808e757)
```

For branch you have to `cd` in the directory, or change `$GITDIR` before running `git status`.